# Backbone Marionette Fetch Hitting Rails Index Action Instead of Show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, marionette

I noticed in my debug params today that the individual Backbone model when being fetched is hitting the index action instead of the Show action.

My Backbone Marionette app starts in the Index view:

index.html.erb

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="header-region"></div>
  <div id="main-region"></div>
  <div id="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer-region"></div>
<div id="dialog-region"></div>

<%= javascript_tag do %>
  $(function() {
    SampleApp.start({
      environment: "<%= Rails.env %>"
    });
  });
<% end %>
```

Because it's operating within the index view, will any fetch calls always resolve on the index action of the controller? Is there a way that I can force the backbone model fetch call to hit the Show action of the controller instead of the index action?

The weird thing is the Network call shows /posts/17.json in the response rather than /posts.json I'd expect to see on the index view. Yet the actual call seems to be hitting the index action in the controller.

EDIT:

Approuter:

```
@SampleApp.module "SurveysApp", (SurveysApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class SurveysApp.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes:
      ""            : "list"
      ":id"         : "show"
      ":id/take": "take"

  API =
    list: ->
      new SurveysApp.List.Controller

    show: (id, survey) ->
        new SurveysApp.Show.Controller
            id: id
            survey: survey

    take: (id, survey) ->
      new SurveysApp.Take.Controller 
        id: id 
        survey: survey

    newSurvey: (surveys) ->
      new SurveysApp.New.Controller 
        surveys: surveys

  App.vent.on "survey:clicked", (survey) ->
    App.navigate "/" + survey.id
    API.show survey.id, survey

  App.vent.on "new:survey", (surveys) ->
    API.newSurvey surveys

  App.vent.on "take:survey:button:clicked", (survey) ->
    App.navigate "/" + survey.id + "/take"
    API.take survey.id, survey

  App.vent.on "survey:list", ->
    App.navigate "/"
    API.list()

  App.addInitializer ->
    new SurveysApp.Router
      controller: API
```

Model:

```
@SampleApp.module "Entities", (Entities, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class Entities.Survey extends App.Entities.Model
    urlRoot: "surveys"
    url: ->
      if @.get('take') == true
        url = @urlRoot + "/" + @id + "/fetch.json"
      else 
        url = @urlRoot + "/" + @id + ".json"
      return url 

    sync: (method, model, options) ->
     @mySyncFunction method, model, options

    mySyncFunction: (method, model, options) ->
      if (method == 'GET')
        options.url = model.url
      else
        options.url = @urlRoot + "/" + @id + ".json"
      return Backbone.sync(method, model, options)

    defaults: 
      status: "Draft"
      number_taken: 0
      survey_limit: 500
      take: false

    relations: [
      type: Backbone.HasMany
      key: "questions"
      relatedModel: Entities.Question
      reverseRelation: 
        key: 'survey'
        includeInJSON: 'id'
    ]
```

Which extends this:

```
@SampleApp.module "Entities", (Entities, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class Entities.Model extends Backbone.RelationalModel

    initialize: ->
      @listenTo(@, 'change', @modelChanged)

    modelChanged: ->
      @hasChangedSinceLastSync = true


    sync: (method, model, options) ->
      options = options || {}
      success = options.success
      options.success = (resp) ->
        success && success(resp)
        model.hasChangedSinceLastSync = false
      super method, model, options

    destroy: (options = {}) ->
      _.defaults options,
        wait: true

      @set _destroy: true
      super options

    isDestroyed: ->
      @get "_destroy"

    save: (data, options = {}) ->
      isNew = @isNew()

      _.defaults options,
        wait: true
        success:   _.bind(@saveSuccess, @, isNew, options.collection, options.callback)
        error:    _.bind(@saveError, @)

      @unset "_errors"
      super data, options

    saveSuccess: (isNew, collection, callback) =>
      if isNew ## model is being created
        collection?.add @
        collection?.trigger "model:created", @
        @trigger "created", @
      else ## model is being updated
        collection ?= @collection ## if model has collection property defined, use that if no collection option exists
        collection?.trigger "model:updated", @
        @trigger "updated", @

      callback?()

    saveError: (model, xhr, options) =>
      ## set errors directly on the model unless status returned was 500 or 404
      @set _errors: $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)?.errors unless /500|404/.test xhr.status

  API =
    newModel: (attrs) ->
      new Entities.Model attrs

  App.reqres.setHandler "new:model", (attrs = {}) ->
    API.newModel attrs
```

Controller:

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_survey, only: [:show, :fetch, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /surveys
  # GET /surveys.json
  def index
    unless signed_in?
      redirect_to signin_path
    end
    @surveys = Survey.where(user_id: cookies[:theoremreach_user_id])
  end

  # GET /surveys/1
  # GET /surveys/1.json
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json
      format.csv { send_data @survey.to_csv }
      format.xls #{ send_data @survey.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
    end
  end

  def fetch
    unless signed_in?
      redirect_to signin_path
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json
    end
  end

  # GET /surveys/new
  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
  end

  # GET /surveys/1/edit
  def edit
    # unless signed_in?
    #   redirect_to signin_path
    # end
  end

  # POST /surveys
  # POST /surveys.json
  def create
    @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @survey.save
        if @survey.status == "Submitted"
          SurveyMailer.survey_created(@survey).deliver
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @survey }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /surveys/1
  # PATCH/PUT /surveys/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @survey.update(survey_params)
        if @survey.status == "Submitted"
          SurveyMailer.survey_created(@survey).deliver
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /surveys/1
  # DELETE /surveys/1.json
  def destroy
    @survey.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to surveys_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_survey
      @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def survey_params
      params.require(:survey).permit(:number_taken, :survey_limit, :title, :status, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Routes.rb:

```
resources :surveys

  resources :surveys do 
    get :fetch, on: :member
  end
```

Basically the goal of what I'm trying to do is get the `surveys#1/take` to hit the Show action in the controller which doesn't require a user to sign-in (anyone should be able to take a survey), while surveys/1 or surveys index should hit the fetch/index actions respectively and require sign-in (before editing/viewing a list of surveys/what not).

Right now the surveys#1/take route is hitting the Index action on the controller though and requiring the user to sign-in.

Comment: Not enough code here to help - do you have an AppRouter defined and implemented? What does the definition of your model look like?

Comment: Sure thing - I posted my router and model

Comment: I also included the rails controller/routes file.

Comment: Model should have an `id` attributed setted, if you wish to `GET show/:id`. If there is no `id` it will `GET index`. Try to `console.log(model.id)` before fetch.